# Settings file, can't access values

Tags: c#-4.0, settings

I'm having problem accessing the settings file in a C# (Winforms) application under .Net 4. 
I have a string variable called Version which is set to scope=application, the access modifier for the  settings file is set to public.

in the form_load I'm trying to access this using

```
string version = Properties.Settings.Default.
```

but intellisense does not show the settings key (Version) after the final dot.

I've added a using for Properties.Settings but this makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you already had a successful build after adding the `Version` setting?

Comment: Yes, I did a clean solution and full rebuild.

Comment: I've since discovered that I can easily access settings created in the menu item project | properties and then in the settings tab, which is fine for this project, however it would be good to know how to do this from a settings file.

Comment: The `project | properties` tab auto-generates a `Settings.cs`. When that is compiled, then Intellisense has something to suggest. If the settings are merely in the config file, they aren't C# objects and thus can't be referenced in code or Intellisense.

Comment: the problem may be related to 'where' you're trying to access that property, try yo put that inside the Main method of your class

Answer (score 4):

Check the name of the class on the generated Designer.cs. Your custom settings will only be included on the default Settings.cs if you named your settings file "Settings.settings".

If you named it something else (as I did when I discovered this), the value for your setting key Version can be accessed from _class_name_.Default.Version